# Adjacent character and string literal tokens

Tags: c, string, char, language-lawyer, c11

It's a familiar fact that in C you can write `"a" "b"` and get `"ab"`. This is discussed in the `C11` standard:

> In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of adjacent character and identically-prefixed string literal tokens are concatenated into a single multibyte character sequence.

The phrase "character and..." would seem to suggest you can get the same results by writing `'a' "b"`, but I've never come across that usage and GCC and the Microsoft compiler both reject it. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it should be read "character string literal", not "character literal".

Comment: The complete para is *In translation phase 6, the multibyte character sequences specified by any sequence of adjacent character and identically-prefixed string literal tokens are concatenated into a
single multibyte character sequence. If any of the tokens has an encoding prefix, the resulting multibyte character sequence is treated as having the same prefix; otherwise, it is treated as a character string literal. Whether differently-prefixed wide string literal tokens can be concatenated and, if so, the treatment of the resulting multibyte character sequence are implementation-defined.* and..

Comment: And it's also under section *6.4.5 String literals*. So it's rather obvious that the standard refers to character string literals, not character literals.

Comment: I believe it should be interpreted as "any sequence of adjacent *character string literal* tokens and *identically-prefixed string literal* tokens." It's a very confusing contraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, maybe we're getting a wrong meaning out of the statement made there.

Let me quote from `C11`, chapter §5.1.1.2, *Translation phases*, paragraph 6,

> 6. Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

Here, we don't have any confusion between `char` and *string* literals, it's clearly mentioned about *string* literals only.