# Need to take user inputted string and create several files with user string as part of them

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to create a number of files in which I define the first part of the filename, then use a user inputted string for the second part. 
so if user puts in "filename", I want to create 1TEMPfilename, 1FLUXfilename, 1PRESSUREfilename

so far:

```
main ()
{

  char filename[64];

  printf("Enter the Runfile ID (e.g. jul0476.a\n");

  fgets(filename,50,stdin);

  //create new files

  FILE *fp;

  fp = fopen('1FINALTEMP'filename,"w");

}
```

this generates an error, any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Please show the error message that you receive.

Comment: you question is - how do i concatenate strings in c. Use snprintf

Comment: error is:  warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
  fp = fopen('1FINALTEMP'filename,"w");
                   ^
warning: character constant too long for its type
error: expected ')'
  fp = fopen('1FINALTEMP'filename,"w");
                                          ^
note: to match this '('
  fp = fopen('1FINALTEMP'filename,"w");

Comment: use `strcat(str1,filename)` where str1 is `"1FINALTEMP"` before fopen

Comment: if I concatenate the strings won't it change the filename string I'm trying to use? So I'd end up with 1TEMPfilename and 1FLUX1TEMPfilename.... ect?

Comment: using strcat i get an Abort trap 6 error

Comment: Create a 2nd buffer: `char full_name[64]; snprintf(full_name, 64, "1TEMP%s", filename); fp = fopen(full_name, "w");`

Comment: cool that worked! except all my file names end in "?" but I'll sort that out later! Thank you @JohnnyMopp

Comment: More likely, they all end with newline (which you typed when entering the name on stdin, but didn't ever remove).

Comment: BTW, you ought to `#include <stdio.h>` and turn your compiler warnings up a bit - relying on implicit function definitions can cause surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that `fgets()` would read in the trailing newline (`\n`) as well. You may want to remove that.

```
fgets(filename,50,stdin);
filename[strlen(filename)-1]='\0';
```

After that make the new file names.

```
char names[3][60];
sprintf(names[0], "1TEMP%s", filename);
sprintf(names[1], "1FLUX%s", filename);
sprintf(names[2], "1PRESSURE%s", filename);
```

Then use these strings as argument to `fopen()` like

```
fopen(names[0], "w");
```

And check if `fopen()` succeeded by having a look at its return value. If it's `NULL`, some error has occurred.

As for `fp = fopen('1FINALTEMP'filename,"w");` giving error, `'1FINALTEMP'` is a string and not a character literal. Single quotes are for character literals. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3683613/5375464).

And only adjacent string *literals* are concatenated as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30664974/5375464).

> Adjacent string literal tokens are concatenated.

ie, in `printf("%s", "hello " "world");`, the `"hello " "world"` would become `"hello world"`.

But that's only for string literals.

Edit: `snprintf()` is preferred over `sprintf()` as the latter may write out of bounds if the string to be written is too large to be stored in the string to which writing occurs. With `snprintf()`, you can specify the number of bytes to be written.

```
char name[60];
snprintf(names, 60, "1TEMP%s", filename);
```

Comment: This fixed everything! Thanks so much

Answer (score -1):

Try taking a string variable which store filename from fgets and then use '+' and concatenate what you provide (1Finaltemp) then pass it to file pointer like fp= fopen( myNewFile,w)

Comment: You can 't concat strings with `+` in [tag:C].